# Container of derived objects / smart pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, polymorphism, containers

Lets say i have:

```
class Base {...};
class Derived1 : public Base {...};
class Derived2 : public Base {...};
class Derived3 : public Base {...};

class Store {
public:
    void Add(const Base&);    //Adds mix of Derived1/2/3
private:
    vector<const Base*> vec;    
    vector<shared_ptr<const Base> > vec_smart;
};

//------------------------------------------------------

void Store::Add(const Base& b){
    vec.push_back(&b);    //got sliced
}
```

When using vector of pointers to Base, it got sliced. I suppose i have to use smart pointers but I cant get it to work.

I tried something like:

```
auto tmp = make_shared<const Base> (b);
vec_smart.push_back(shared_ptr<const Base>(b));
```

But it still got sliced. What Iam doing wrong?

EDIT:
I have << operator in Base class that calls virtual print in Derived classes.

```
ostream & operator <<(ostream & os, const Base & x) {
    x.print(os);
    return os;
}

void Base::print(ostream& os) const {
   os << "Base";
}

void Derived1::print(ostream& os) const {
   os << "Derived1";
}
```

When i call

```
cout << b;
```

In Store::Add it outputs fine but when I iterate over vector after it got stored all i get is "Base"

```
ostream & operator <<(ostream & os, const Store & x) {
    for (auto it = x.vec.begin(); it != x.vec.end(); ++it) {
        os << *(*it) << endl;
    }
    return os;
}
```

Is it a bad design?

Comment: How did you determine it "got sliced"? It can't get sliced if it is a pointer.

Comment: `make_shared<const Base>(b)` performs a slice.  `vec.push_back(&b)` does not slice anything.  `shared_ptr<const Base>(b)` probably doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to guess you didn't declare the relevant methods in `Base` as `virtual`. Try this:

```
struct Base
{
  virtual void print(std::ostream& os) const { os << "Base"; }
  virtual ~Base() {}
};

struct Derived1 : Base
{
  void print(std::ostream& os) const { os << "Derived1"; }
};
```

ans so on. Note I have only used `struct` here to save me typing `public` a few times.

Here is a working example:

```
#include <vector>
int main()
{
  Base b;
  Derived1 d;
  std::vector<const Base*> v{&b, &d};

  for (auto it = v.cbegin(); it != v.cend(); ++it)
  {
    std::cout << *(*it) << std::endl;
  }

}
```

Output:

```
Base
Derived1
```

You can see it in action [**here**](http://ideone.com/dGzKOt).

**Edit** Your code has *undefined behaviour* because you are storing pointers to temporaries:

```
Store a("aaaaaaa");
a.Add(Derived("abc", 5));
a.Add(Derived("def", 6));
```

This version works as expected:

```
Store a("aaaaaaa");
Derived d0("abc", 5);
Derived d1("def", 6);
a.Add(d0);
a.Add(d1);
```

**Edit 2**: from your comments:

> Lets say Iam forced to use a.Add(Derived("abc", 5)); What can I do with it in my implementation?

You could make `Add` a template:

```
template <typename T>
void Add(const T& elem)
{
  vec.push_back(new T(elem));
}
```

or

```
template <typename T>
void Add(const T& elem)
{
  vec_smart.push_back(std::make_shared(elem));
}
```

Comment: Edited my question. I have to be wrong in my design.

Comment: @Bilcus You have not shown the crucial part. Your problem is consistent with my guess that your member is not `virtual`. I edited my post to use methods similar to yours.

Comment: [This](http://ideone.com/nmJCUl) is basicaly my code and problem with it. Before storingto vector it outputs fine but after that, not. @juanchopanza

Comment: @Bilcus Yuor code has undefined behaviour. You are storing pointers to temporaries.

Comment: Oh, thanks I see now. Can I have a hint on how to implement this properly? Is this where smart pointers come into play?

Comment: One last thing. Lets say Iam forced to use `a.Add(Derived("abc", 5));` What can I do with it in my implementation?

Comment: Can I have a hint please to my previous question?

Comment: @Bilcus I added something.

Comment: Wow, perfect. Thanks a lot. I ended up with multiple if statements that worked but were ugly. This is just perfect.