# Passing inherited class type as argument

Tags: c++, inheritance, methods

I have got problem with passing inherited class type as argument to method that takes its base class type.

```
class Base {...}
class Derived : public Base {...}
class Container {
    vector<Base*> cont; //1
 public:
    void addToCont(Base x) { //2
        cont.push_back(&x);
    }
}

int main() {
   Container c;
   c.addToCont(Derived(p1,p2)); //3
}
```

1) I suppose I need to have container of pointers to objects to keep it working

2) Here is error in conversion from Derived to Base

3) I am not supposed to change this call. I tried

```
Derived d(p1,p2);
c.addToCont(d);
```

with

```
addToCont(Base& x)
```

and it worked for me.

My problem is that I've got 3 derived classes and I don't want to overload the add method 3 times. I guess I will have to add some virtual method or some type-casting to those classes, but I couldn't find anything about that. I am novice in inheritance and quite confused of this. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Container of derived objects / smart pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23181518/container-of-derived-objects-smart-pointers)

Comment: Please post your real code, not this pseudo-snippet full of syntax errors and undeclared indentifiers. See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Summary of duplicate: you have undefined behaviour because you are storing pointers to temporaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some notes:

1. Must use a vector of pointers to the Base, so that you can handle objects from the hierarchy. Goes without saying that you're probably better off with using some kind of *smart pointer* instead of raw pointers, but that goes in preferences and how much you love risk.
2. Using `void addToCont(Base x)` is wrong because even if you were only adding a Base object, you will be adding a pointer to a local variable (the pass-by-value parameter)
3. Using `void addToCont(Base &x)` the way you do it with a local `Derived d` is wrong too, for the same reasons as before, as soon as `d` goes out of scope, you're left with a dangling pointer stored in the pointer
4. Calling `addToCont(Derived(...))` passes a temporary object. That must be taken into account when you think about your memory management.
5. Not sure why you see a need for overloading addToCont for all Derived classes, that's not what you did on `void addToCont(Base &x)`
6. The solution (if you keep to the raw pointers) is to do `void addToCont(Base *x)` there you can pass a pointer to Base or to any Derived. Again, you must be mindful about the memory management. You're Derived object probably needs to be allocated with a `new Derived(...)` and you must watch about who owns it, and who has responsibility for deleting it (for example, when the Container object is destroyed).
7. You probably should remember to make virtual the destructor of Base, because you will be destroying Derived objects from Base pointers, and if the destructor is not virtual, the object will only be partially destroyed.

If `addToCont(Derived(...))` call is absolutely required, then you might want to consider to use the `void addToCont(Base &x)` defininition.... but them, you must clone the object before inserting it into the vector:

```
void addToCont(const Base &x) { //2
    cont.push_back(x.clone());
}
```

But then.. you need a `virtual Base *clone() const` method to be implemented (at least) in the Derived classes, that will produce a Base pointer with an exact copy of the Derived object, involving extra copies of the objects and extra cloning...

Answer (score 0):

Derived classes are only "possible to use" when they are either references or pointers. If you convert a class to a base-class without a reference or pointer, you won't be able to use it as a derived class later.

If you are actually storing pointers in your container, then I would make it explicit, so:

```
class Container {
    vector<Base*> cont;
 public:
    void addToCont(Base* x) { 
        cont.push_back(x);
    }
    ~Container()
    {
       for(auto a : cont)
       {
           delete a;
       }
    }
}
```

And in main:

Container c;
   c.addToCont(new Derived(p1,p2));

Note that in your original code, the `Derived(p1, p2)` will get destroyed again just after call to `addToCont(...)`, so your array would be pointing to a "dead" element of the Derived class. Which was probably not what you actually wanted (since it's undefined behaviour to ever use that element, and building up a container full of useless elements is pretty pointless)

Comment: well, I am not supposed to change the call in main, so it must stay as it is (no new word). I just figured out that I should be able to make a template for addToCont method, I think it will work

Comment: Then you probably shouldn't really use an array of pointers, either!

Comment: then will I be able to store all derived objects in one container?